# Current directory 'dot slash' (./) in WSDL (XSD path)

Tags: path, xsd, jaxb, wsdl

The xsd in the wsdl I'm working with is referenced with a path beginning with 'dot slash' (./).

```
<xsd:schema>
    <xsd:import namespace="urn:my.name.space.be" schemaLocation="http://fictive.url.be:11001/path/to/wsdl/my-service?XSD=./xsd/my-service.xsd"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

The path is valid, I can access the xsd in my browser; it works also fine with Soap UI for instance. But when I try to generate a proxy with Jdeveloper, I run into a 'WebServiceException: : Error creating model from wsdl: 'ExampleType' is already defined'.

If I remove the 'dot slash' (`XSD=xsd/my-service.xsd`), the exception doesn't occur anymore and everything is ok.

Is this a bug? Why does this happen? Is there some way to avoid this without necessarily having to modify the wsdl?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it happens has to do with how the  XML Schema set is being put together by your JDeveloper tool. `'ExampleType' is already defined'.` means one of the two things:

- the **same** XSD defining `ExampleType` is loaded **twice** or more using **different base URI**s: different "string" representation, yet when dereferenced on the server, it points to the same resource;
- `ExampleType` is defined in **two** or more (different) XSD "places": could be inside the WSDL types/schema section, and/or external XSD files.

When you changed the URL, it either makes it invalid (the extra reference is no more) OR JDeveloper URI compare is able to perform correctly.

To diagnose, you have to first figure out what resources are downloaded from where.

Use an HTTP debugger (e.g. use tcpmon as a proxy and monitor the trafic through it) while running JDeveloper and the other tool. Compare the trace and look for the URLs each tool is trying to resolve.

Compare the GET header values to see the differences between the tools. Then look at the downloaded content. It should give you a good idea as to what to do next. If you still can't figure it out, update the question with additional info.